# Change color of a label based on value from JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

My JSON "R1" returns either 1 or 0. With 1 I want to make my label blue. What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
myJson = {
    "product": "IPX800_V4",
    "R1": 0,
    "R2": 0,
    "R3": 0,
    "R4": 0,
    "R5": 0,
    "R6": 0,
    "R7": 0,
    "R8": 0,
    "R9": 0,
    "R10": 0,
    "R11": 0,
    "R12": 0,
    "R13": 0,
    "R14": 0,
    "R15": 0,
 }
```

The parse from monitor works 0 and 1.

My label is called `led1` and should become blue when "r1" = 1

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var led1: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.201/api/xdevices.json?key=apikey&Get=R")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, respense, error) in
            if error != nil
            { print("error") }
            else
            {
                if let content = data
                {
                    do
                    {
                        let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                        let r1 = myJson["R1"]
                        if let r1 = myJson["R1"] { print(r1!) }
                        if ( r1 > 0) { self.led1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue }
                    }
                    catch {    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your label connected in storyboard?

Comment: Please include the expected JSON response in your question. Your code doesn't work, since you parse the JSON as a single AnyObject. I can't tell you how to parse it without seeing the JSON you expect, but AnyObject is not the correct way regardless.

Comment: my json : {
    "product": "IPX800_V4",
    "R1": 0,
    "R2": 0,
    "R3": 0,
    "R4": 0,
    "R5": 0,
    "R6": 0,
    "R7": 0,
    "R8": 0,
    "R9": 0,
    "R10": 0,
    "R11": 0,
    "R12": 0,
    "R13": 0,
    "R14": 0,
    "R15": 0, }

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to update the UI on the main thread. In Swift 3:

```
if ( r1 > 0) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.led1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
}
```